# Foreach binding with custom binding for google map markers

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js, foreach

Right now I have a custom binding that takes info from an observableArray inside my viewModel, iterates through a for loop, and creates a marker for each location. I would like to get rid of the for loop and use a foreach binding in my DOM but I can't seem to get it to work the way I hoped.

http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/ZbPPBm?editors=101

I tried removing all my for loop stuff (for (...){} and [i]) inside my custom binding and tried adding a foreach binding using the foreach without a container element method

```
<!-- ko foreach: locations -->
  <div id='marker' data-bind="marker: { locations }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

but I just couldnt figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: If you're trying to pass a location from `locations` into the `marker` binding then it would look like `data-bind="marker: $data"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the following binding to iterate locations:

```
<!-- ko foreach: locations -->
     <span data-bind="marker: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Example**

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.marker = {

    infowindow: null,

    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var map = bindingContext.$parent.mapControl;
        var location = valueAccessor().location;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small_withshadow&chld=swim|bbT|" + location.name + "|24527A|E0EBEB",
            title: location.name
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.marker.openInfoWindow(map, marker);
        });
    },



    openInfoWindow: function (map, marker) {
        var contentString = '<div">' + marker.getTitle() + '</div>';
        if (this.infowindow) {
            this.infowindow.close();
        };
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(50, 0),
        });
        map.setZoom(9);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        this.infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
            map.setZoom(7);
            //map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        });
    }
};


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {

 
    //1.create map
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.55, -77.0167),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


    var viewModel = {
        locations: ko.observableArray([
          { name: "Virginia Beach", lat: 36.852926, lng: -75.977985, state: 'Virginia' },
          { name: "Chincoteague Island", lat: 37.93317, lng: -75.378809, state: 'Virginia' },
          { name: "Atlantic City", lat: 39.364283, lng: -74.422927, state: 'New Jersey' },
          { name: "Ocean city", lat: 38.336503, lng: -75.084906, state: 'Maryland' },
          { name: "Oakacroke", lat: 35.114615, lng: -75.98101, state: 'North Carolina' },
          { name: "Nags Head", lat: 35.957392, lng: -75.624062, state: 'North Carolina' },
          { name: "Emerald Isle", lat: 34.677940, lng: -76.950776, state: 'North Carolina' }
        ]),
        mapControl: map
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 75px;
  font-size: 135px;
  color: #24527A;
  font-family: 'Voltaire', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 7px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
#map { 
  height:800px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<!-- ko foreach: locations -->
     <span data-bind="marker: {location: $data}"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[Modified example: Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOZmEZWHubd6MojTjlLq?p=preview)